# OGR Error on object.File size

Tags: qgis

I am trying to join attributes by location for two datasets. One is the openzoomstack from the ordnancesurvey site, whereas the other consists of areas at risk of floods across the UK.

I get the following error when I join by attributes and the loading bar stops at 6%:

> WARNING    Feature creation error (OGR error: Failed to write shape object. File size cannot reach 4294967260 + 10347572.)

How can I overcome this?